# JBoss app-specific logging that's NOT copied in server.log?

Tags: logging, jboss, log4j, categories, appender

I followed the instructions [**in this question**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9272170/application-specific-logging-in-jboss-5-1) (basically creating a new RollingFileAppender and adding a category to direct output to it), and it works, but the entire contents of my app-specific log is ALSO present in server.log, so all I've done is *copy* not *redirect* the output.  Anyone know how to redirect and NOT have server.log keep a copy?

Edit: I have tried this on another instance, this time adding not a 2nd RollingFileAppender as above, but enabling a SyslogAppender.  In this case, all logging output has ceased and since I've set the bar fairly high (FATAL) for the new appender's category, I'm not getting any pings yet.

Why would one duplicate and the other redirect output?  Both have the same root logger category.  Neither one behaves how I wanted.

(PS: I am currently using JBoss Portal 2.6.2 GA as well as AS 7, but more concerned with the former if there are material differences.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to set `use-parent-handlers="false"` in your logging subsystem in JBoss AS 7 configuration.

Source: [how to exclude logger categories from server.log on JBoss AS 7.0.2.Final](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12379454/971423)